# pandas groupby single column but add contents of multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

|  | Time | Buy | Sell | Bin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 09:15:01 | 3200 | 0 | 3573.0 |
| 1 | 09:15:01 | 0 | 4550 | 3562.0 |
| 2 | 09:15:01 | 4250 | 0 | 3565.0 |
| 3 | 09:15:01 | 0 | 5150 | 3562.0 |
| 4 | 09:15:01 | 1200 | 0 | 3563.0 |
| .. | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 292 | 09:15:01 | 375 | 0 | 3564.0 |
| 293 | 09:15:01 | 175 | 0 | 3564.0 |
| 294 | 09:15:01 | 0 | 25 | 3564.0 |
| 295 | 09:15:01 | 400 | 0 | 3564.0 |

(Disregard 'Time' currently just using a static value)

what would be the **most efficient way to
sum up all the Buys and sells within each bin and remove duplicates**

Currently im using

Step1.

```py
final_df1['Buy'] = final_df1.groupby(final_df1['Bin'])['Buy'].transform('sum')
```

Step2.

```py
final_df1['Sell'] = final_df1.groupby(final_df1['Bin'])['Sell'].transform('sum')
```

Step3.

```py
##remove duplicates
final_df1 = final_df1.groupby('Bin', as_index=False).max()
```

using agg or sum or cumsum just removed all the other columns from the resulting df

Ideally there should be distinct bins with sum of buy and/or sell

The output must be

|  | Time | Buy | Sell | Bin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 09:15:01 | 3200 | 0 | 3573.0 |
| 1 | 09:15:01 | 450 | 4550 | 3562.0 |
| 2 | 09:15:01 | 4250 | 3625 | 3565.0 |
| 292 | 09:15:01 | 950 | 25 | 3564.0 |

Comment: are you looking for `df.groupby(['Bin']).sum().sum(axis=1)`?

Comment: @Epsi95 I edited my question with expected output to make things clearer. I need the sell and buy numbers for each bin separately

Comment: did you try `df.groupby(['Bin'])[['Sell', 'Buy']].sum()`?

Comment: @Epsi95 That works!! but is there anyway to prevent losing 'Time' column from the result (though i could add it on later), i tried groupby( ['Bin'],['Time'])[[.....]].sum() but that throws an error TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: You need to specify what kind of aggregation for `Time` since it cannot be summed. One way is to use `df.groupby("Bin").agg({"Time":"first", "Sell":"sum", "Buy":"sum"})`.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be achieved by using `pivot_table` from `pandas`.

Here is the simple recreated example for your code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'buy':[1,2,3,0,3,2,1],
                 'sell':[2,3,4,0,5,4,3],
                 'bin':[1,2,1,2,1,2,1],
                 'time': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
                })

df_output=df.pivot_table(columns='bin', values=['buy','sell'], aggfunc=np.sum)
```

Output will look like this:

```
bin     1   2
buy     8   4
sell    14  7
```

In case you want the output you mentioned:

we can take the transpose of the above dataframe output:

```
df_output.T
```

Or use a `groupby` as below to input `dataframe`:

```
df.groupby(['bin'])[['sell', 'buy']].sum()
```

The output is as below:

```
   sell buy
bin     
1   14  8
2   7   4
```

If you also need `time` in the `dataframe`, we could do it by using and separating the `aggregate` function for `each column`:

```
df.groupby("bin").agg({ "sell":"sum", "buy":"sum", "time":"first"})
```

The output is as below:

```
    sell    buy time
bin         
1     14      8    1
2     7       4    1
```

Comment: that sums the two columns for each bin, but essentially trasposes my df.. as the columns become rows.. is there a transpose function for the result? and also anyway to keep 'Time' column in the result?